# StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 01 in Client Server connection

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, objectinputstream

Firstly, I know there are some questions regarding StreamCorruptedExceptions, but barely any regarding the "Invalid type code: 01".

I have a local client connected to a local server. The Client tries to send a serializable "Task_Data" Object to the Server. The code that I use to send is (with clutter removed):

---

```
    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

    Task_Data task = new Task_Data();
    task.setCheckMale(true);
    task.setCheckAdult(true);
    task.setAdditionalInfo("testing");
    task.setTakeNotes(true);
    task.setTakePhoto(true);
    oos.writeObject(task);
    oos.flush();
```

---

Now on the receiving end (server) I have:

---

```
    Task_Data task = (Task_Data) ois.readObject();
    System.out.println(task.getAdditionalInfo());
```

---

Eclipse throws this error: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 01

What is strange is that the transmission work for "primitive" types like UTF without any problems.

Maybe the cause lies in my serialization, the Task_Data class is:

---

```
public class Task_Data implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -226273890693695870L;

private boolean checkMale = true;
private boolean checkAdult = true;
private boolean takePhoto = true;
private boolean takeNotes = true;

private String additionalInfo = null;

private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
    out.writeBoolean(checkMale);
    out.writeBoolean(checkAdult);
    out.writeBoolean(takePhoto);
    out.writeBoolean(takeNotes);
    out.writeUTF(additionalInfo);
}


private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    checkMale       =   in.readBoolean();
    checkAdult      =   in.readBoolean();
    takePhoto       =   in.readBoolean();
    takeNotes       =   in.readBoolean();
    additionalInfo  =   in.readUTF();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `writeObject()` method will be executed during Serialization, because it agrees with the canonical signature for such methods, but your `readObject()` method won't, because it doesn't. So there is an asymmetry present, which could cause any error, including this one.

But I don't know why you've written explicit code to do what Serialization would already do by default anyway. I would get rid of the `readObject()` and `writeObject()` methods altogether, and any existing serialized streams, and re-test.

You must also make sure to use the same ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream for the life of the socket. There are headers on these streams, and starting new ones at one end will confuse the other end.

Comment: My source probably did not make it clear, but I do use the same ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream for the life of the socket. When my ServerWorkerThread runs and creates the socket, it also creates the OOS and OIS and then goes into an endless while loop where it receives the data.

Comment: Thanks! You're right for those cases manually writing/reading is useless. However, I want to be able to send bitmaps and for those a manual implementation is neccessary, I think. What should I do to fix the readObject method here?

Comment: I don't understand, isn't it according to [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) `private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
     throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;`